# How to turn off shaders?

Tags: lighting, godot

Whenever I import something in Godot it looks like it's covered in some mushy slimy glittery stuff, I don't like it.... Garbaj on youtube showed that it's possible to turn shaders off and just render the pure texture with no external lighting, like in blender... but it was far from a tutorial and I have no idea how to do it.

[image: Image example]

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I import something in Godot it looks like it's covered in some mushy slimy glittery stuff

If I recall correctly, the way Godot 3.x did roughness scaling was wrong. If possible, edit the materials increasing roughness to compensate.

However, more importantly, the default environment gives an ugly look (e.g. a pure white material looks blue). So you will want to tweak it. In particular:

- Change the `tonemap_mode` (you don't want Linear). Optionally increase the `tonemap_white` value.
- Reduce `ambient_light_sky_contribution`. Optionally change the ambient light color.
- For the sun light add a directional light to your scene (give it a large max distance. *Rotate the directional light to align it with the sun in the sky.*

Note that this approach lets you tweak the procedural sky freely, which you might want to do for depicting different times of day. *Or you may want to replace the procedural sky with something else.*

*Speaking of time of day, you can add a `WorldEnviroment` to your scene, set its `environment`, and animate it with an `AnimationPlayer`. In which case you probably want to animate the directional light in conjunction.*

---

> Garbaj on youtube showed that it's possible to turn shaders off and just render the pure texture with no external lighting

If you want a material to not interact with lights you can mark it "`unshaded`" (you find it under "Flags" in the inspector of a `SpatialMaterial`).